# How to make scales on axises in chartjs equal?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to make each axis on my scatter plot increment by the same value, start with the same value, and end with the same value. This is my code right now:

```
const resultcfg = {
          type: "scatter",
          data: {
            datasets: [{
              data: x.map((value, index) => ({ x: value, y: y[index] })),
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(37, 93, 150, 0.8)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(37, 93, 150, 1)',
              pointRadius: 1,
              pointHoverRadius: 2,
            }]
          },
          options: {
            title: {
              text: "PDF Chart",
              display: false
            },
            legend: {
              display: false
            },
            elements: {
              point: {
                radius: 0
              }
            },
            tooltips: { enabled: false },
            hover: { mode: null },
            scales: {
              x: {
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom',
              },
              y: {
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'left',
              }
            },
          }
        };
```

This is what returns when I run the code:

[image: v]

I essentially want this graph to be square how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would just have to set the size of the `div` that wraps the chart, with a square values, add set the property `maintainAspectRatio` to `false`, in the `options`.
Than the chart should be more or less square.

**Here a demo, how I would do this:**

```js
let x = [-5 , -4 , -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let y = [-6, -5, -4, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

// get highest value of x and y
let maxAxis = Math.max(...y.concat(x).map(i => Math.abs(i)) );

const resultcfg = {
          type: "scatter",
          data: {
            datasets: [{
              data: x.map((value, index) => ({ x: value, y: y[index] })),
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(37, 93, 150, 0.8)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(37, 93, 150, 1)',
              pointRadius: 1,
              pointHoverRadius: 2,
            }]
          },
          options: {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            plugins:{
                legend: {display:false},
            },
            elements: {
              point: {
                radius: 0
              }
            },
            tooltips: { enabled: false },
            hover: { mode: null },
            scales: {
              x: {
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom',
                max: maxAxis,
                min: -maxAxis
              },
              y: {
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'left',
                max: maxAxis,
                min: -maxAxis
              }
            },
          }
        };
  new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"),resultcfg);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>  

<div class="chart" style="height:184px; width:184px;">
    <canvas  id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
```

**Update:**
If you want the Axis to be exactly in the middle of the value range you just need to get the highest value of both axis and set the `min` and `max` of the scale property.
*(the demo example is updated)*

It's not pixel prefect, but almost square
[image: screenshot Chart]

Comment: My scatter plot is graphed on a square HTML element but for some (0,0) is still not in the center of the graph and the maximum of the y-axis is 4 while the maximum of the x-axis is 5... I've tried manually setting the maxes of each axis but that doesn't do anything

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understood what you need correctly, but I updated my answer. I hope fits your needs.

Comment: @Xenon757 does this work for you, or do you need it exact?